Material Top Tabs Navigator swipe error on Android
Button navigation hangs in the middle of the screen.
On the screen there is a main tab with another tab inside.
// create a TabNavigator
function renderSubmenuTab(TabNavigator, telas, telaInicial) {
    return (
        <TabNavigator.Navigator
            tabBar={props => <TabBarSubmenu {...props} />}
            tabBarPosition='bottom'
            initialLayout={{ width: metrics.screenWidth }}
            initialRouteName={telaInicial}>
            {telas.map(({ nome, componente, opcoes }) => (
                <TabNavigator.Screen
                    key={nome}
                    name={nome}
                    component={componente}
                    options={{ ...opcoes, swipeEnabled: true }}
                />
            ))}
        </TabNavigator.Navigator>
    );
}
//create a TabNavigator
const JuridicoTab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
const ComponenteSubmenuJuridico = () =>
    renderSubmenuTab(JuridicoTab, telasSubmenuJuridico, 'Acoes');

// main component
const Routes = () => {
  return 
      <TabMenuPrincipal.Navigator
        screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
        id='MenuPrincipal'
        initialRouteName='Noticias'
        tabBar={props => <TabBar {...props} />}>
        <TabMenuPrincipal.Screen
            name='Noticias'
            component={ComponenteSubmenuNoticias}
        />
        <TabMenuPrincipal.Screen
            name='Juridico'
            component={ComponenteSubmenuJuridico}
        />
        <TabMenuPrincipal.Screen
            name='Agenda'
            component={ComponenteSubmenuAgenda}
        />
      </TabMenuPrincipal.Navigator>
}


Print to view the error

By clicking on the buttons navigate to the correct tab. It works on iOS.
